# Redirect from html pages with trailing slash

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

Please provide me how to make a redirect in Magento if we add at the end of url trailing slash

http://example.com/blog.html/ to http://example.com/blog.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do it with a htaccess rewrite rule (assuming you are using apache instead of nginx on the server)

Something like this should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html//$ $1.html [L]
```

**Edit:**

I'm not an expert with nginx configurations however i had a quick search and came up with some information.

Something like the below in your nginx config

```
server {
    rewrite ^(/.html\//)\$ $1.html last;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have nginx server, so what can we do here?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps but i'm not an expert with nginx setup (yet)